# After selecting Category, subcategory will show the sub items in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following problem. I have a form, with many inputs, and i want to filter the subbcategory. After select the category, the right subcategory items will shown in php

I have that:

```
<!-- Blog category-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="mainCategory">category</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="mainCategory">
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option name="' . $row['IDCat'] . '">' . $row['mainCategory'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- subcategory-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="subCategory">Subcategory</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="subCategory">
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM subcategory");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option name="' . $row['IDSubCat'] . '">' . $row['subCategory'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use ajax to load subcategory on selection of category

Comment: "SELECT * FROM subcategory where category= chosen cateogry" you should use where to find  the subcategory of the category you picked

Comment: Try understanding [this example](http://www.techsofttutorials.com/ajax-country-state-city-dropdown-using-phpmysql/).  it may help you a lot.